# How to close modal on hardware back button in ionic app?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, progressive-web-apps

I'm using Ionic 5 in my pwa application (angular framework), and I want to close the opening modal/popover (if exist) when the user uses the hardware back button..

I couldn't find any solution online that works on ionic 4+ pwa applications.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a handler for the backbutton.

Cordova: 
Inject **Platform** in a constructor and

```
this.platform.backButton.subscribe(() => {
  // close modal here
});
```

Capacitor:

```
import { Plugins, AppState } from '@capacitor/core';
const { App } = Plugins;
App.addListener('backButton', () => {
  // close modal here
});
```